# Navigation bar overlapping status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there any way to fix this? If I drag navigation bar little more down, background is shown which I don't want. Swift 2.1.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height constraint of your UINavigationBar to `60`, for example, as:

[image]

Comment: This fixes the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this navigation bar part of a `UINavigationController`? If not, I think you want to have your view controller be the delegate of the `UINavigationBar` and implement the `positionForBar` method to return `UIBarPositionTop`. That should cause the navigation bar to leave some room at the top for the status bar.

Comment: I like this solution. Note: In swift, you want to return .topAttached NOT just .top

Answer (score 1):

This may happen, if you force a view controller to show the app's status bar in viewDidDisappear.